# rabbitmq with scheduled spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

```
  public void processSubscriptionByCategoryOrAuthor(Book book) {
        Page<Subscription> page = subscriptionRepository.findAllByCategoryOrAuthor(book.getCategory(), book.getAuthor(), PageRequest.of(0, BATCH_SIZE));
        page.getContent()
                .stream()
                .map(subscription -> subscription.getCustomer().getEmailAddress())
                .forEach(email -> rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("email-queue", email));
        while (page.hasNext()) {
            page = subscriptionRepository.findAllByCategoryOrAuthor(book.getCategory(), book.getAuthor(), page.nextPageable());
            page.getContent()
                    .stream()
                    .map(subscription -> subscription.getCustomer().getEmailAddress())
                    .forEach(email -> rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("email-queue", email));
        }
    }
```

```
    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void sendNotifyk(String to) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("xxxx");
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(BOOK);
        message.setText("new item");
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
```

its applicaiton JavaMailSender , I have class subscription where I have subscriptions of customers ,

in method proccessSubscription i take emails and send i to queue in rabbitMQ , next step is receive once per day and send it via JavaMailSender .
I just need to send all emails in queue once per day .
I Tried to use @Scheduled but this method can't have parameter and i don't know how to receive in good way this emails from queue . data must te durable .

Any sugestion please ?

Comment: Not very clear what you want. I understand @Scheduled is too static for you (can have a cron expression). So, create a Quartz job https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule .

Comment: @PeterMmm i just want to delay receive message from rabbitMQ , and i can't use Scheduled cause method annotated with it can't have parameter when you use RabbitListener you must declare parameter in method like this   RabbitListener(queues = "email-queue")
    public void receive(String s) {
        sendNotifyNewBook(s);
    } and then I can't add Scheduled in this case

Comment: As I said before, your question is not clear, confusing. Maybe try to reword your question. 
I try a guess: in the `.forEach(email `, instead of calling `rabbitTemplate` could you schedule a quartz job for each email that executes once a day that call to `rabbitTemplate` ?

Comment: you can used a task Scheduler https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler